# Open TCP connection if FF 49

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

i was looking for a way to open TCP connection in FF 49 - of course in addon. Earlier it was possible with something like (according to other older Stackoverflow questions):

```
var tcpSocket = Cc["@mozilla.org/tcp-socket;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIDOMTCPSocket);     
var socket = tcpSocket.open("127.0.0.1", 3000);     
socket.onopen = function() { 
    socket.send(sendText);  
}
```

However it seems not to work anymore, "@mozilla.org/tcp-socket" seems to be not existing any more.
Does anyone know how can one open a connection with current FF?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using this:

```
let { TCPSocket } = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm", {});

if (TCPSocket) {
  let tcpSocket = new TCPSocket(location, port, options);
}
```

Where Cu = Components.utils;

The way you are using was deprecated in version 43 or in a version around 40... I am not completely sure in which one.

Comment: Tried the following:


`function createTCPSocket(location, port, options) {  
  let { TCPSocket } = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm", {});
  if (TCPSocket) {
    return new TCPSocket(location, port, options);
  }  
  
}

function handleSendClick(state) {
 let socket=createTCPSocket("127.0.0.1", 4000); 
 socket.send("HELLO");
}`

However i get an error nsresult 0x80004005 at the line of send.

Comment: Did you try initializing the options parameter to the createTCPSocket function (arrayBuffer or string). In this case, it should be string.

Comment: I tried this:

`let socket=createTCPSocket("127.0.0.1", 4000, { binaryType: "string" });`

However the result is the same.